# Is OfficeWritter PowerPointTemplate thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, officewriter

I am using OfficeWritter to create a PPT file in multiple thread application where I got the error regarding memory. So Can anyone let me know if can use OfficeWriter in multi threaded application.

I am getting error at when ppt start process: `ppt.Process();`

Comment: I am getting error at when ppt start process: =>    ppt.Process();

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please be more specific with your question and add "the error regarding memory" to this post. Do you have a Stacktrace? Please provide us some piece of code where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes OfficeWriter controls are considered thread safe. If you run into an issue in multi threaded environments it may be bug.

Source: Former developer on OfficeWriter